# ArrayAdapter<> does not clear in onPause(), android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview, android-sdcard

I have been researching this a while,  but nothing. My `ArrayAdapter<>` for my `GridView` is in a `Fragment` tab. I have concluded that because it is in a fragment, that when I browse tabs then go back to my photos tab, instead of re-uploading images from scratch, it instead uploads images and add the same ones to the adapter. This results in 2 sets of identical images, but what I need is only a single set to upload upon revisiting the tab.

I tried putting `adapter.clear()` followed by `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` into my `onPause()` fragment lifecycle method. So when the fragment is not visible anymore, all adapter items clear, and when the fragment is visible again, it loads a fresh copy of images from my SD card. But this is not working, it still adds the new set of images in addition to the previously loaded set. Anyone know how to get the adapter cleared so I don't get the same images added every time I revisit the tab? Or if there is another way to do it, that I'm not aware of ... Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to everyone for the contributions, I finally found a work around that helped. I logged all of my `adapter` variables at different stages, and found that no matter where I clear it, it will always post a duplicate set in the `loadSDCard()` method, so it must have been coming from there. So I just made a condition on my adapter to prevent it from loading again. I noticed that my adapter was already loaded after coming back from the other tabs, by using `getCount()` on it. This came from my `PhotoTab.java` and is the missing piece:

```
if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
            adapter.addAll(loadSDCard());

            // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
            for (int i = 0; i < (24 - photoList.size()); i++) {

                adapter.add(new PhotoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder)));
            }

        }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

See my answer below, I found out the real reason why the duplicates were happening in the first place.

[image]

**PhotoTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class PhotoTab extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    File[] files;
    ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> adapter;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    public PhotoTab() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);
        adapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.photo_grid_item);
        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.addAll(loadSDCard());

        // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
        for (int i = 0; i < (24 - photoList.size()); i++) {

            adapter.add(new PhotoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder)));
        }

        return v;
    }


    private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> loadSDCard() {

        try {
            // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
            File cutePhotosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CutePhotos");
            // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
            files = cutePhotosDir.listFiles();

            for (File singleFile : files) {
                String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();

                // this method makes size small for the view (to save memory)
                bitmap = decodeSampledBitmap(filePath, 270, 270);

                photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return photoList;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

**GridViewPhotoAdapter**

```
    package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

/**
* Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
*/
// package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.azurespot.R;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
 */
public class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> {

    public Context context;
    private int resourceId;
    Bitmap bm;

    public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            // stores holder with view
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        PhotoGridItem photoGridItem = getItem(position);

        if (photoGridItem != null) {
            bm = photoGridItem.getImage();
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // positioning the image in the GridView slot
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(270, 270));
        }

        return row;

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
    }

}
```

**PhotoGridItem**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 3/19/15.
 */
public class PhotoGridItem {

    private Bitmap image;

    public PhotoGridItem(Bitmap image) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you log file paths? Maybe you're adding thumbnails as well as original pictures.

Comment: Good to see that you upload images, at least. I see progress!

Comment: Thanks @TheOriginalAndroid! I love how you've been helping me here and there lately. :)

Comment: I just read your update and the fix "adapter.getCount()". This code seems reasonable to me. But I have to wonder about code before the if check  "adapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter". I thought that would make getCount return 0 all the time.

Comment: Thanks TOA, I think it only sets it to zero if there is no null check. So since I have a null check, when I browse back to the tab, it is not null (since I already saw the tab at least once), so the new object is not created. Good point though, that null check was also crucial to solving this. I think I put that on a while back and forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment.onPause() isn't tied to the visibility of your Fragment. Fragment.onPause() is tied to it's encapsulating Activity.onPause(). i.e. Fragment.onPause() will only be called after Activity.onPause() is called.

If you want to update your Fragment when it becomes visible, I recommend you use Fragment.setUserVisibleHint() OR you use a ViewPager.onPageChangeListener() to let you know when your Fragment has been selected and update its contents accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Karim, that is good to know. Turns out I found another fix.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this modified your codes in `onCreateView(...)`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

    // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);

    if(adapter == null)
        adapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.photo_grid_item);

    // Set the Adapter to GridView
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(adapter.getCount()>0)
        adapter.clear();

    adapter.addAll(loadSDCard());

    // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
    for (int i = 0; i < (24 - photoList.size()); i++) {

        adapter.add(new PhotoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder)));
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //that was missing!!!  

    return v;
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks X, I tried your code, it seems like it should work! But it doesn't I still get those repeated images added when browsing back to the tab from another tab. I have tried so many things, I just don't understand it!

Comment: Actually I tried a modification on this and it worked, thanks so much!! Been such a headache this one, for days. I modified my question to include the right code, you could add that to your answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: `if(adapter.getCount()>0) adapter.clear(); adapter.addAll(loadSDCard());` is same as your update codes, isn¨t it? My codes are forcing to reload data. Of course your codes would be better if you do not want to refresh data each time fragment back.

Comment: No it's different, because first of all the adapter does not need to be cleared, only checked to see if it's full or not. Second, your code runs the `adapter.addAll(loadSDCard());` method at all times, and that is where the additions keep happening. So that is also why the adapter doesn't matter to be cleared or not, because it adds double images even if cleared. My fix doesn't really address why the additions were getting added (they were coming from the SD card method), but it works well enough for my purposes.

Comment: Actually they are same, your update codes are just avoiding reloading data(no need refresh UI), my codes are reloading data but forget refreshing UI, so I need adding `notifyDataSetChanged`, I modify answer then should work. Hope this clear.

Comment: Thanks, I already used the code I have from the update. But again, it's not the adapter. The duplicates were happening in the SD card method. I logged it when the adapter was cleared, and it would say 0, but then I would go back to the tab and the SD card method would run and load duplicates. I know it seems the same, but it's not, I tried it. But your code did get me to try different things, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment, in `onCreateView`, try checking whether `savedInstanceState` is null like this:

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     //Add all your images to the adapter
 }
```

That way you should be sure that images are only added to the adapter when the view of the fragment is loaded the first time.

Comment: Thanks, I wish that would have worked, but still the same problem. Here is where I added it: `if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            adapter.addAll(loadSDCard());
        }`, in my PhotoTab.java.

Comment: Could you by the way fix your code examples. You accidentally duplicated your fragment code, but didn't post your adapter code.

Comment: Ah, it could be that `savedInstanceState` is always null, unless I override `onSaveInstanceState()`, like it says here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31732. I will try this.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I added this: `@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle){
        super.setArguments(Bundle.EMPTY);
    }` , but problem is still there.

Comment: Ah well. Hopefully someone with a faster brain comes by. My suspicion is that `onCreateView` is called every time you return to the activity, and that some variable is not cleared when this happens, thus duplicating values. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, I really do. No one else has been able to help, I'm starting to think it's a weird bug, because when I go to my video tab, then back to the photo tab, there is NO repeat of the images. It's only when I go from the text or audio tab. Yet I've checked the tab and adapter code for all of the tabs and it's identical. So it makes no sense.

Comment: I hope you figure it out. Only advice I can give is to give the debugger a try, and check if the variables are what you expect - For example that the `files` array fills with the number of entries you expect in the `loadSDCard` method.

Comment: I think savedInstanceState check works better in onActivityCreated method or in the subclass of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The onCreateView of PhotoTab fragment is triggered several times, like when user switches apps (Android may need to unload your app to gain memory) and when rotate the screen. So from your code, I think they could all be duplicates within time. I think your design is such that the reloading of images is done in the onCreateView method. One disadvantage may be performance, but let's not worry about that for now.

My suggestion is to modify loadSDCard() to check if a file is already processed or displayed. In your code sample:

```
private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> loadSDCard() {
    ...
    for (File singleFile : files) {
...
       // Check if this is a new bitmap file
       if (photoList.contains(bitmap) == false) {
          photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks TOA, I added that code, but it's still adding a new set every time I browse back to the tab. :( I added it like this: `for (File singleFile : files) {
                String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();

                // this method makes size small for the view (to save memory)
                bitmap = decodeSampledBitmap(filePath, 270, 270);
                // Check if this is a new bitmap file
                if (!photoList.contains(bitmap)) {
                    photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));
                }
            }`

Comment: TOA, what did you mean that I should not run `loadSDCard()` in `onCreateView()`. Is there another option? I'd love to know, thanks.

Comment: Noni, I just realized code "if (!photoList.contains(bitmap))" may not work mainly because the object bitmap will be different each time. Better to check for filenames or the full path. Now it seems does not matter, just a thought. It's good it's working for you now. But do remember the code technique of using contains method in ArrayList or HashTable.

Comment: Thanks TOA, I did do a log on `files` and that was exactly right! It showed only the hash code for `Bitmap`, but it was different every time I browsed to another tab and came back. And thanks for the suggestion of the `contains()` method. I was searching through `File` and `ArrayAdapter`, but didn't think to search in `ArrayList`.

Comment: Noni, About another way to run loadSDCard(). You could create a Service which monitors a certain directory and notifies your Activity. Some apps create a service for constant monitoring. For now since you have the check of getCount = 0, it seems sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

While I found a work around for the duplicate problem, the real reason I was getting duplicates is because I made my `loadSDCard()` method return an `ArrayList<>`. I realized I did not need to do that. So when I changed my method to `void` instead, I could refresh the tab and the SD Card would load, but it would start from scratch each time, and load the photo items over the old items, without duplicates. I don't really know why returning an `ArrayList<>` variable (I was returning `photoList`) in that method made it do that, but hopefully someone else will be helped if you get duplicates in the future.